# IBM Code Page 473 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, codepages

Not quite a question but hopefully it'll stick.

I searched high and low for this, but could not find it, so typed it out manually. Hopefully it'll be of some use to others, probably just people porting DOS code to JS.

If however anyone knows of a better way to do this, eg: is there a JS binding to access chars in a codepage, I would LOVE to know

```
charMap = [
    ' ', '☺', '☻', '♥', '♦', '♣', '♠', '•', '◘', '○', '◙', '♂', '♀', '♪', '♫', '☼',
    '►', '◄', '↕', '‼', '¶', '§', '▬', '↨', '↑', '↓', '→', '←', '∟', '↔', '▲', '▼',
    '_', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?',
    '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
    'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_',
    '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
    'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~', '⌂',
    'Ç', 'ü', 'é', 'â', 'ä', 'à', 'å', 'ç', 'ê', 'ë', 'è', 'ï', 'î', 'ì', 'Ä', 'Å',
    'É', 'æ', 'Æ', 'ô', 'ö', 'ò', 'û', 'ù', 'ÿ', 'Ö', 'Ü', '¢', '£', '¥', '₧', 'ƒ',
    'á', 'í', 'ó', 'ú', 'ñ', 'Ñ', 'ª', 'º', '¿', '⌐', '¬', '½', '¼', '¡', '«', '»',
    '░', '▒', '▓', '│', '┤', '╡', '╢', '╖', '╕', '╣', '║', '╗', '╝', '╜', '╛', '┐',
    '└', '┴', '┬', '├', '─', '┼', '╞', '╟', '╚', '╔', '╩', '╦', '╠', '═', '╬', '╧',
    '╨', '╤', '╥', '╙', '╘', '╒', '╓', '╫', '╪', '┘', '┌', '█', '▄', '▌', '▐', '▀',
    'α', 'ß', 'Γ', 'π', 'Σ', 'σ', 'µ', 'τ', 'Φ', 'Θ', 'Ω', 'δ', '∞', 'φ', 'ε', '∩',
    '≡', '±', '≥', '≤', '⌠', '⌡', '÷', '≈', '°', '∙', '·', '√', 'ⁿ', '²', '■', ' '
];
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Isn't this what `String.prototype.fromCharCode` is for?

Comment: If you want to post a solution you found, and if it hasn't already been asked, phrase your post in the form of a question that fully describes the problem, then post your own answer below.